# Dart json serializable - how to return a const IconData

Tags: flutter, dart, serialization, json-serializable

Storing the IconData on the server and retrieving it with the JsonSerializable, lead to the following error on the Jenkin android build.

> This application cannot tree shake icons fonts. It has non-constant instances of IconData at the following locations:

The following code dto to build the icon data object:

```dart
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class DrawerIconDataDto extends IconData {
  const DrawerIconDataDto(
    super.codePoint, {
    super.fontFamily,
    super.fontPackage,
    super.matchTextDirection,
  });

  /// Create a new instance from a json.
  factory DrawerIconDataDto.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return _$DrawerIconDataDtoFromJson(json);
  }

  /// Convert this instance to a json.
  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$DrawerIconDataDtoToJson(this);
}
```

Even adding const to the following class lead to the error. I tried to add a const to the factory but it is not possible.

How can I get a constant DataIcon object from the server using JsonSerializable and without modifying the Jenkins configuration (not allowed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Dart, `const` means that the compiler can determine the value at compile time. Obviously, this does not apply to data retrieved from a server.

So, you cannot retrieve `const` data from a server.

What you could do is have all possible IconData values as `const` instances in you code, and retrieve an identifier from the server.